# How to write SQL to query avg of data from timestamp every hour of the day

Tags: sql, charts, db2

I have Climate data stored in table such as (Temperature,Humidity,CO2,Save_Timestamp) in realtime.

How can i write a sql to select average of data by every hour of the day
because when i do full select and render it on html5 with Chart.js 
It's BOOM!!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

For avg for current date by hour:

```
select hour(Save_Timestamp) HourSave, 
avg(Temperature) avgTemperature, avg(Humidity) avgHumidity, avg(CO2) avgCO2 
from yourtable 
where date(Save_Timestamp)=current date
group by hour(Save_Timestamp)
```

For avg for all date by hour:

```
select date(Save_Timestamp) DateSave, hour(Save_Timestamp) HourSave, 
avg(Temperature) avgTemperature, avg(Humidity) avgHumidity, avg(CO2) avgCO2 
from yourtable 
group by date(Save_Timestamp) , hour(Save_Timestamp)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Save_Timestamp,112) AS Date,
       DATEPART(hh,Save_Timestamp) AS Hour,
       SUM(TEMPERATURE)/COUNT(*) AS AvgTemp
FROM CLIMATE_TABLE
GROUP BY
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Save_Timestamp,112),
       DATEPART(hh,Save_Timestamp)
```

This might get you what you are looking for.